# Distance to the nearest non-zero value in a list?

Tags: python, list

I have list like this one:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

and I'd like to get a list that describes the distance to closest non-zero value for each element. In this case it would be:

```
[3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: What is not working with your attempt?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem individually. A good way to show this effort is to include a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you finished before posting, especially [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Initialize the list of distances with infinity.
2. Loop over the list and keep track of the distance to the last-seen non-zero value. If the distance is smaller than the distance stored in the list (currently infinity), update the `distances` list.
3. Repeat step 2 but iterate over the list backwards.

Code:

```
lst = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

# initialize the distances to infinity
distances = [float('inf')] * len(lst)

# loop over the list twice, once from the left and once from the right
for indices in [range(len(lst)), range(len(lst)-1, -1, -1)]:
    # keep track of the distance to the last seen non-zero value
    distance = float('inf')

    for i in indices:
        # when we find a non-zero value, set the distance to 0
        if lst[i] != 0:
            distance = 0

        distances[i] = min(distances[i], distance)

        # with each step we take, increase the distance by 1
        distance += 1

print(distances)
# output: [3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(lst):
    ans = [0 for x in range(len(lst))]
    last_non_zero = -len(lst)
    last_edited = -1
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i] != 1:
            for j in range(last_edited+1, i):
                ans[j] = min(abs(i-j), abs(j-last_non_zero))
            last_edited = i
            last_non_zero = i
    return ans
```

The time complexity is O(n).

Comment: you might want to generalize to `if lst[i] != 0`. he doesnt say the input has to be all 0's and 1's

Comment: @stackPusher Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np 
test = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
non_zero_idx = np.array([idx for idx, x in enumerate(test) if x is not 0])
```

At this point you have the idx of all values that are non-zero. All you have to do is take the minimum between the difference of that and the idx of the value for each value.

```
distances = [min(abs(idx-np.array(non_zero_idx))) for idx, x in enumerate(test)]
distances
```

[3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0]

Answer (score 0):

You can use two list comprehensions to assemble the distances marching forward and backward through the list:

```
s = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

forward = [s[i:].index(1) if x!=1 else 0 for i, x in enumerate(s)]

s_r = s[::-1]

backward = [s_r[i:].index(1) if 1 in s_r[i:] else 0 if x==1 else float('inf') for i, x in enumerate(s_r)][::-1]
```

Then you can zip the two resulting lists together and take the minimum distance at each index:

```
final = [min(i,j) for i, j in zip(forward, backward)]
```

Yields:

```
[3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0]
```